# xamarin how to set carouselview currentpage on startup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

hi im using this carouselview:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64639210/18463835

and I want to set 3th page on carousel view home page when opening page  but I can't.
im tried this:

```
            MainPageCarouselView.CurrentItem = 2;
```

its not working. i have 5 pages now but i think all pages is 10+, i want set main carouselView item to center on first start, also set indicator view to center page.
my carouselView:

```
<CarouselView
  x:Name="MainPageCarouselView"
  IndicatorView="{x:Reference MainContentPageViewIndicatorView}"
  IsSwipeEnabled="True"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MainContentPageViewSelector}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding _mainContentPageViewItemsSource}"
  Loop="True"
  PeekAreaInsets="35"/>
  
<IndicatorView
  x:Name="MainContentPageViewIndicatorView"
  Margin="0,50,0,80"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  IndicatorColor="White"
  IndicatorsShape="Circle"
  SelectedIndicatorColor="Black"
  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

now have 5 pages but its will 10+ and this is on center page
[i want make this page on center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbKPU.png)

Comment: You need to set Position, not CurrentItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set;

```
MainPageCarouselView.Position = 2;
```